# MySQL - How to check if a value exists before appending to a TEXT Field?

Tags: php, mysql

On duplicated record, I want to update the record by appending a string to the TEXT column in table, on the condition that the appending value does not already exist in that TEXT column.

I have come so far with my query

```
INSERT INTO events (event_id, event_types)
VALUES ("1", "partyEvent")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE event_types = CONCAT(event_types, ",testEvent")
```

Is there a such check with MySQL, or is necessary that I fetch the record and do the comparison myself with PHP?

Comment: Have you tried it?  It should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `event_types` is a denormalized field, containing a comma-separated sequence of text strings. With respect, this is a notorious database design antipattern. The next programmer to work on your code will be very unhappy indeed.

I'll answer your question even though it pains me.

First of all, how can you tell whether a particular string occurs within a comma-separated set of text strings? [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) can do this.

```
FIND_IN_SET('testEvent', event_types)
```

returns a value greater than zero if `'testEvent'` shows up in the column.

So we can use it in your `event_types =` clause. If `FIND_IN_SET` comes up with a positive number, you want `event_types = event_types`, that is, an unchanged value.  If not, you want what you have in your question.  How to do this? Use [`IF(condition,trueval,falseval)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if). Try this:

```
  ...UPDATE event_types = IF(FIND_IN_SET('testEvent',event_types) > 0,
                             CONCAT(event_types, ',', 'testEvent'),
                             event_types)
```

There's a *much* better way however.  Make a new table called `event_types` defined like this.

```
CREATE TABLE event_types (
    event_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    event_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (event_id, event_type)
)
```

This has a compound primary key, meaning it cannot have duplicate `event_type` values for any particular `event_id`.

Then you will add a type to an event using this query:

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO event_types (event_id, event_type)
                         VALUES (1,       'testEvent');
```

The `IGNORE` tells MySQL to be quiet if there's already a duplicate.

If you *must* have your event types comma-separated for processing by some program, this aggregate query with [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will produce them..

```
  SELECT e.event_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.event_type ORDER BY t.event_type) event_types
    FROM events e
    LEFT JOIN event_types t ON e.event_id = t.event_it
   GROUP BY e.event_id
```

You can find all the events with a particular type like this.

```
  SELECT event_id FROM event_types WHERE event_type='testEvent')
```

**Pro tip**: Comma separated: bad.  Normalized: good.

Don't worry, we've all made this design mistake once or twice.

Comment: For the future readers don't mis the fact GROUP_CONCAT has a default max length of 1024 bytes like mentioned in the documentation.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

Comment: I really appreciate the time you put in this answer to cover all the angles, I will look into it and might redesign the current structure. I will this as reference for future projects as well. Thanks